# Python matplotlib 3d bar function

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to add strings to the axes in Axes3D instead of numbers?

I just started using the matplotlib. I have used Axes3dD to plot similar to the example given on their website (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/bars3d_demo.html). Note that one must use the last verson (matplotlib 0.99.1), otherwise the axis gets a bit freaky. The example use this code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np  

fig = plt.figure()  
ax = Axes3D(fig)  
for c, z in zip(['r', 'g', 'b', 'y'], [30, 20, 10, 0]):
    xs = np.arange(20)
    ys = np.random.rand(20)
    ax.bar(xs, ys, zs=z, zdir='y', color=c, alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

Now to my problem, I cant rename the axis to what I want. Instead of numbers i need to name the staples to string names. This I only want to do in two dimensions - the x dimension, and the z dimension (depth). I have tried to use this command:

```
ax.set_xticklabels('First staple',(0,0))
```

I get no error message but nevertheless no sting. If anyone can answer this question I would be most delighted!

Answer (score 2):

Your actually on the right path there. but instead of a string you will want to pass a list or tuple to set_xticklabels(). You may also wish to adjust the center location for the label with set_xticks().

You may also find this function of use get_xmajorticklabels(). It will return the rendered tick labels. So you may also be able to adjust the value from its results.

Answer (score 0):

Also retrieve the axis data, work on that and set it back to the renderer, turned out to be much simpler for me ;) other than that, what NerdyNick says